# draw.io - how to snap to minor grid on arrow press

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Sometimes when I move items on the grid with the arrow keys, I don't want them to move a single pixel, I would like them to move to the minor line of the grid so I can easily and quickly align items.

Is there a way to do this or is there another way of aligning items? I am using the multi-lane flow chart to diagram the flow between web services.

Going to https://www.draw.io/shortcuts.svg doesn't seem to have a way to set this.

Comment: did you try with ctrl + arrow keys (or shift or alt or some combo between them) like on other similar apps? (just a guess)

Comment: Yeah looks like if I used `shift+arrow`, it will work. I was hoping to have it snap to grid on arrow press and then use a modifier key for more finite movement but this should be fine.

Comment: glad to hear that. I shall add it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>ARROW KEY</kbd>** could do the trick

Comment: For me, it looks like this only moves the object in increments of a grid unit, but doesn't snap that object to the grid. So if the object is halfway between grid lines before you move it, then it will still be halfway between grid lines after the move. If it starts aligned, it will stay aligned though.